# How many sequences of lenght 2n, made of n "+1"s and n "-1"s and such that every partial summation of the first k terms is nonnegative, are there?

Tags: combinatorics

What's the number of sequences
$$(u_{1},...,u_{2n})$$
with $u_{i}=+1,-1$, such that:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{2n} u_{j}=0\quad\hbox{and}\quad \sum_{j=1}^{k} u_{j}\geq 0$$
I realized that $u_{1}=+1$ and $u_{2n}=-1$, but I don't know how to proceed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequences so defined are Dyck words of lenght 2n and it has been proved (by Désiré André in 1887) that they are in number of $$C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}{2n\choose n} = \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!\,n!},$$
the nth Catalan number.

Comment: So you actually know the answer, but yet you asked.  If you simply googled it, you would find a proof very easily.  For example, http://mathcircle.berkeley.edu/BMC6/pdf0607/catalan.pdf.

Comment: I didn't know the answer: the deleted one of a user here, who suggested me to check for Catalan numbers, was quite useful.