# n 1's and n 2's

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Find the number Ways in which n 1's and n 2's can be arranged in a row so that up to any point in the row, number of 1's is more than or equal to no. of 2's?

I tried making cases like arranging 1's and 2's that alternatively but that will be only one case. How to make other cases?

Comment: Look at Catalan numbers.  The Wikipedia and MathWorld articles should have a discussion on the application of them to your problem (or something analogous).

Comment: The answer to this is called the $n$th [Catalan Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). The question has been asked here before (possibly with different symbols in place of 1 and 2); one moment while I search ...

Comment: Hmm, that was harder to find than I thought, but here is one earlier instance: [How many sequences of lenght 2n, made of n "+1"s and n "-1"s and such that every partial summation of the first k terms is nonnegative, are there?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339700/how-many-sequences-of-lenght-2n-made-of-n-1s-and-n-1s-and-such-that-every)

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank You!!